# Error while running ECS container with read-only root filesystem

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, amazon-ecs

We have a Java application with spring framework and I am trying to enable read-only root filesystem for the container. I have tried modifying the docker file to provide a writable path for the application but I keep getting the below error

`{"dateTime":"2023-04-21T00:53:12.922Z","type":"ERROR","stage":"dev","logger":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication","class":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication","method":"reportFailure","file":"SpringApplication.java","line":865,"thread":"main","message":"Application run failed","stack_trace":"j.n.f.FileSystemException: /tmp/tomcat.8091.7261574515025557054: Read-only file system\n\tat s.n.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)\n\tat s.n.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)\n\tat s.n.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)\n\tat s.n.f.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Unknown Source)\n\tat j.n.f.TempFileHelper.create(Unknown Source)\n\tat j.n.f.TempFileHelper.createTempDirectory(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.nio.file.Files.createTempDirectory(Unknown Source)\n\tat o.s.b.w.s.AbstractConfigurableWebServerFactory.createTempDir(AbstractConfigurableWebServerFactory.java:189)\n\t... 19 common frames omitted\nWrapped by: o.s.b.w.s.WebServerException: Unable to create tempDir. java.io.tmpdir is set to /tmp\n\tat o.s.b.w.s.AbstractConfigurableWebServerFactory.createTempDir(AbstractConfigurableWebServerFactory.java:195)\n\tat o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:188)\n\tat o.s.b.w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182)\n\tat o.s.b.w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160)\n\t... 16 common frames omitted\nWrapped by: o.s.c.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to create tempDir. java.io.tmpdir is set to /tmp\n\tat o.s.b.w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163)\n\tat o.s.c.s.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577)\n\tat o.s.b.w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)\n\tat o.s.b.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)\n\tat o.s.b.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:448)\n\tat o.s.b.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339)\n\tat o.s.b.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1365)\n\tat o.s.b.SpringApplica...\n"}`

The docker file config is

```
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} xxx.jar

# Create a writable directory for temporary files
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/tmp && chown spring:spring /usr/src/app/tmp

# Configure the application to use the new directory for temporary files
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/src/app/tmp"

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/xxx.jar"]
```

Is there anything else I need to do within the application for it to use the path provided in the docker file?

Comment: What version of Java are you running? The `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable isn't a universal environment variable, it seems to be mostly used by Tomcat and other servlet containers. It appears that your version of Java does not use that environment variable. You could always simply add `-Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/src/app/tmp` to the `ENTRYPOINT`.

Comment: Hey @MarkB, we are using Java 11. I updated the docker file as such but still getting the same error.

```FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} component-pgs-amex-message-processor-service.jar

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/tmp && chown spring:spring /usr/src/app/tmp
# ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/src/app/tmp"
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/src/app/tmp","-jar","/component-pgs-amex-message-processor-service.jar"]```

Comment: I want to set readrootfilesystem flag to true and run the containerize java application as fargate service , After setting flag to true , I got the same error ,  Any solution ?